# How to retrieve all instances that matches a given type using Koin Dependency Injection (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, ktor, koin

How do you achieve the following using Koin DI:

```
single { AValidator() } bind IValidator::class
single { BValidator() } bind IValidator::class
single { CValidator() } bind IValidator::class
single { DValidator() } bind IValidator::class
```

In the class where I want to have all validators injected I use the following:

```
val validators: List<IValidator> by inject()
```

Expecting that all different implementations of interface `IValidator` are injected automatically.

I know that is actually supported in Kodein, where you would simply do:

`val validators: List<IValidator> by kodein.allInstances()`

Would love to know whether this is possible within Koin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the documentation, I can do something like the following:

```
 single(name = "validators") {
        listOf(AValidator(), BValidator(), CValidator(), DValidator())
    }
```

And retrieve it with:

```
val validators: List<IValidator> by inject(name = "validators")
```

It works for now, but injecting a single validator of the list above would for example not work.

For more details: https://insert-koin.io/docs/1.0/documentation/reference/index.html

Feel free to add another solution!

Comment: @shkschneider The thing now is, that you cannot inject them individually, but only as a list of validators. I'll accept the answer for now. Hopefully Koin will support injecting a list of the same type in the near future. Thnx!

Comment: @M Ahayan, there is much better answer avaliaveble which IMO should be the accepted one. Please consider it.

Answer (score 14):

With Koin 2+, you can now declare your instances individually

```
single { AValidator() } bind IValidator::class
single { BValidator() } bind IValidator::class
single { CValidator() } bind IValidator::class
single { DValidator() } bind IValidator::class
```

Then use `getAll<TInterface>` to request all of them

```
val validators: List<IValidator> = getKoin().getAll()
// with lazy
val validators: List<IValidator> by lazy { getKoin().getAll<IValidator>() }
```

And use `bind<TInterface, TImplementation>` to request a single instance

```
val validator: IValidator = getKoin().bind<IValidator, AValidator>()
```

Source
https://start.insert-koin.io/#/getting-started/modules-definitions?id=additional-types

Answer (score 1):

Built in Koin `getAll()` is also not working for me, regardless of version. So its either a bug that persisted for years or poor documentation. However this is my custom solution, koin version `3.3.0`.

```kotlin
@OptIn(KoinInternalApi::class)
inline fun <reified T : Any> getAllCustom(): List<T> =
    KoinJavaComponent.getKoin().let { koin ->
        koin.instanceRegistry.instances.map { it.value.beanDefinition }
            .filter { it.kind == Kind.Singleton }
            .filter { it.primaryType.isSubclassOf(T::class) }
            .map { koin.get(clazz = it.primaryType, qualifier = null, parameters = null) }
    }
```

And then provide it like this

```
single { 
    SomeClass(getAllCustom()) 
}
```