# Koin analogue to Dagger IntoSet

Tags: android, kotlin, koin

Does Koin provide the functionality of binding several dependencies into a collection, as Dagger does with multibindings?

Let's suppose I have this interface:

```
interface Initializer: (Application) -> Unit
```

And this interface has several implementations, for instance:

```
class LoggingInitializer: Initializer {
    override fun invoke(p1: Application) {
        Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
    }
}
```

The implementations are provided in different modules using `bind` modifier:

```
val coreToolsModules = module {
    single { LoggingInitializer() } bind Initializer::class
}
```

And such modules are installed in the app's Application class:

```
class TestApplication: Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val startKoin = startKoin {
            logger(PrintLogger())
            androidContext(this@TestApplication)
            modules(listOf(coreToolsModules))
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to inject all implementations of Initializer class as a set to my Application class in order to carry out such initialization:

```
    val initializers: Set<Initializer> by inject()

    //in onCreate()
    initializers.forEach { it.invoke(this) }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54374067/how-to-retrieve-all-instances-that-matches-a-given-type-using-koin-dependency-in